# What determines the order Custom VariableListeners are triggered in?

Tags: optaplanner

I've been reading the [`6.2.0.Final` documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#shadowVariable), but I couldn't find any information about what determines the order `VariableListener`s are triggered in. I've tried reordering my source to change the order the `@CustomShadowVariable` annotated methods appear in, but this doesn't appear to have any effect. Is there a preferred method for specifying the update order of listeners?

Comment: See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 6.3.0.CR1 and earlier: **Chaos** (well not really, they are triggered immediately as each genuine planning variable changes, which can drive any man or woman insane)

As of 6.3.0.CR2 (which fixes PLANNER-252, see Ondrej's link): **Order**. The first shadow variable's after method is triggered AFTER the last genuine planning variable has changed. See [this image](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-docs/src/main/docbook/en-US/images/Chapter-Planner_configuration/shadowVariableOrder.png) and the 6.3.0.CR2 docs.